# PHP array by xmlHttp.responseText to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

This is my PHP code

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); 
echo $cars;
```

This is my JavaScript

```
function assign_dt() {
  var cars = xmlHttp.responseText;

    document.getElementById('des').innerHTML = cars;

}
```

I need the values, but they shows me like this "Array" on the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the array to a string - use `json_encode()` for this:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); 
echo json_encode($cars);
```

Comment: I added a bit of explanation to your answer. You should make your answers more clear by explaining why your code works.